# Proof of $n$ being quadratic residue for primes of the form $4n+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> If $4n+1$ is a prime $p$, then $n$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod p$.

For this, I thought I could evoke the quadratic reciprocity law and deduce:

$$\genfrac(){}{0}{n}{4n+1}\genfrac(){}{0}{4n+1}{n}
=(-1)^{(n-1)\frac{4n+1-1}{4}}=(-1)^{(n-1)n}=1
\\\iff\genfrac(){}{0}{n}{4n+1}=(\genfrac(){}{0}{4n+1}{n})^{-1}
=(\genfrac(){}{0}{1}{n})^{-1}=1$$

with Legendre Symbols, but then it occured to me that $n$ need not be prime.
Looking for a workaround, I found I can deduce that the Jacobi-Symbol must be $1$, but If I
I can deduce that the Jacobi-Symbol must be $1$ but this does not necessarily imply that $n$ is a quadratic residue. How do I work around this?

Comment: This might be easier with Euler's criterion. For example, is $4n$ a quadratic residue?

Comment: Yes, then we can invoke multiplicativity-that's elegant.

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity only holds for primes $p$ and $q$. You should probably try another approach altogether.

Comment: Even though this is a nice solution, is there any way one can salvage the idea?

Comment: The Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac n{4n+1}\right)$ matches the Legendre symbol here because $4n+1$ is prime, if I'm not mistaken. So I think your computation is a proof.

Comment: @DeriveFoiler So even though $n$ is not necessarily prime, it still functions?
This seemed to be what I inferred from Apostol, but I was unsure.

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE The Jacobi symbol and the Legendre symbol are equal when the "denominators" are prime, by definition of the Jacobi symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $n$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $-1$ is a quadratic residue.

Indeed, if $-1=a^2 \pmod p$, then $$(2^{-1} a)^2 = 4^{-1}a^2 = (4^{-1})(-1) = (4^{-1})(4n) = n \pmod p$$